# Babel inheritance loses prototype

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Consider the following code

```
const fooBar = parent => class extends parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.foo = 1;
  }
  bar() {
    return 2;
  }
}

class FooBar extends fooBar(Object) {};

console.log(new FooBar());
```

It creates a mixin `fooBar` and derives `FooBar` from it. Running this code, predictably, outputs `FooBar { foo: 1 }`.

Now let's bring in Babel. I tried this with both 6.xx and latest 7.2. Starting in a fresh folder,

```
npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-env
echo { "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] } > .babelrc
npx babel test.js > test2.js
node test2.js
```

Outputs `{ foo: 1 }` - as we see, the prototype is lost. Attempting to call `bar` on the created instance will fail.

Is it a bug in Babel or am I using inheritance in an unsupported way?

**Update:** I'm getting the same result using https://babeljs.io/en/repl so it doesn't appear to be an issue with my installation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Babel does not support extending native objects very well. In Babel 6 this does not work at all, and in Babel 7 it attempts to wrap natives before extending them, but passing it via a function argument bypasses the check.

In this case a simple `class {}` instead of `Object` would suffice.

Related issue/question: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9183